# Cytoscape js + edgeHandles add weight property to edges

Tags: javascript, cytoscape

I can't for the life of me figure out how to add a new data property for edges dynamically created by the user. I'd like to add a weight property to every edge created, being a huge newbie I'm struggling to do so. I'm having a hunch that the edgeParams function of edgeHandles might be the solution, yet after hours of googling, I still unable to grasp an understanding on how that might work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I managed it at last, for anyone in a similiar situation - use the edgeParams: function as follows.

```
          edgeParams: function( sourceNode, targetNode )
      {
        return {
              data: { weight: 75 },
             }
       },
```